# What are Mythic Actions?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

*Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft* features a creature called a [Dullahan](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dullahan). Dullahan has a feature which allows it to come back to life after being reduced to 0 hit points, and doing so allows the Dullahan to use its Mythic Actions, a section of the stat block that looks a lot like Legendary Actions.

The *Monster Manual* has a brief section explaining [Legendary Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#LegendaryActions), is there a similar explanation somewhere for Mythic Actions? I have not been able to find one in *Van Richten's Guide*.

Comment: Re: "Dullahan has a feature which allows it to come back to life".  Should be "...allows it to return to undeath..."?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### "Mythic Actions" are an optional rule given in *Mythic Odysseys of Theros*.

Unfortunately, usage guidance for Mythic Actions is not given in *Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft*, despite its having a creature with Mythic Actions. Usage guidance for Mythic Actions is found in chapter 6 of *Mythic Odysseys of Theros*, in the section ["Mythic Monsters"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/friends-and-foes#MythicMonsters):

> Mythic traits transform battles into truly legendary confrontations, well suited to the climactic battles at the ends of adventures or whole campaigns. Mythic traits are optional; they don’t need to be used during combat with these monsters. If you so choose, you may simply ignore a monster’s mythic trait and mythic actions. If you wish to increase a battle’s stakes, though, using a monster’s mythic trait results in some mid-battle twist that changes the way the monster behaves, restores its resources, or provides it with new actions to use. As a result, the battle becomes deadlier and rages on for longer than most combat encounters. Each monster features an “As a Mythic Encounter” section that highlights its mythic trait, notes how using it changes the difficulty of the encounter and the rewards, and includes read-aloud text you can use mid-battle to signal a terrifying shift in the conflict.

This section in *Theros* goes on to give detailed guidance for using Mythic Actions for three of the monsters presented there; this guidance may be helpful for motivating the use of Mythic Actions with the Dullahan.

*Fizban's Treasury of Dragons* added 13 additional monsters (all dragons) with Mythic Actions, bringing the total to [17 officially published Mythic creatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-is-mythic=t&filter-has-lair=). Like *Van Richten's Guide*, *Fizban's Treasury* is similarly lacking in usage guidance, so *Mythic Odysseys of Theros* remains the only source with any detailed guidance for putting these monsters into play.